# Problem solving numerically a lineal system of equations

Tags: matlab, math

I am currently working on a Matlab script that allows me to solve Boundary-Value Problems using this formula:
[Formula I need to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxMaQ.png)

What I do in order to obtain the equations is the following:

```
%Valors de la frontera:  y''(ti)+p(ti)·y(ti)+q(ti)·y(ti)=f(ti) %  
p=@(t,y) -t;
q=@(t,y) 2;
f=@(t,y) 0;
n=4;
a=0;
b=1;
h=(b-a)/n;
y0=0;
yf=1;
Y=[y0];
% Creamos el vector Y dinámicamente
K = sym('y', [1, n-1]);
Y=[Y K yf];
T = a + (0:n) * h;
t=a;
y=y0;

for i = 2:n
    t = T(i);
    y_prev = Y(i-1);
    y_current = Y(i);
    y_next = Y(i+1);
    equation = (1 - (h/2) * p(t, y_current)) * y_prev + (-2 + h^2 * q(t, y_current)) * y_current + (1 + (h/2) * p(t, y_current)) * y_next - h^2 * f(t, y_current);
    Y(i) = solve(equation, y_current);
end

Y
```

This program solves the BVP correctly. However, it gives the solution vector as such:

```
Y = [0, (31*y2)/60, (900*y3)/1273, 36917/44880, 1]
```

I'd like to see all the values of the vector numerically, instead of depending from y2 or y3.
How can I do it?

Many thanks

Comment: If you want to solve the equations numerically, you should do that and not solve them symbolically.

Comment: Right now you are solving y1 using the value y2 which you don’t yet have. You can’t solve an interconnected system of equations by solving each one in turn independently. It’s a system, a single complex problem, and should be solved as such: write it as a matrix equation `A*y=b`, then solve the equation with `y=A\b`.

Comment: Ok Cris, how should I implement this to my code? I've tried to write it as a matrix, but I don't know where to write it, either inside the for loop or outside. Maybe it's a stupid question, but i am relatively new into coding :)

Comment: It’s not a coding problem, it’s a math problem. Rewrite your equations in matrix form. Implementation then is trivial, it is really just `y=A\b`.